# RStudio (v. 1.2.1335) opens as a hollow/blank window on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, r, rstudio

RStudio worked perfectly when I last used it the night before this morning. But when I opened it up today there didn't appear to be a window, although the program was running according to the task manager. I've used different versions of RStudio (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+double-clicking the program), uninstalling then reinstalling, removing "APPDATA" from the "R" folder, and restarting the computer. I haven't been able to find a solution to a similar error that has worked yet.

Is there another option for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your were one step away from solution. Start RStudio with ctrl and change rendering engine to software. This removes problems with OpenGL. Later you can change this in Global Options - General - Advanced tab.